# How to set autoplay youtube video for IE on the fly?

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer, dom

I need to autoplay youtube video as I click on its thumbnail.
Since IE doesn't support `<EMBED>` tag I need preset all needed values in `<OBJECT>` and then create a new object with my parameters.
So I did something like this:

```
var $newObject = jQuery('<object><param name="play" value="true"/>' + $oldObject.html() + '</object>'); // preparing virtual object on the fly.
$thisObject.html($newObject.html()); //Creating new object
```

That had no effect. So I tried to insert new  to all existing OBJECTs like this:

```
jQuery('<param name="play" value="true" >').prependTo("object");
```

For that I got error in IE that says "Invalid argument" (interesting that in FF and Chrome that aproach worked). 
So I really out of ideas now.
Thanx for help

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is use the Youtube Javascript API and SWFObject.

```
var so_init = {
  params: { allowScriptAccess: "always" },
  atts: { id: "embedVideoPlayer" }
};

// Do this to embed the player.
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=embedVideo",
                   "embedVideo", "480", "385", "9", null, null, so_init.params, so_init.atts);

function player() {
  return document.getElementById(so_init.atts.id);  
}

// Do this to load a video and start it playing.
player().loadVideoById("YOUR-VIDEO-HERE", 0, "large");

<div id="embedVideo">
  You need Flash player 9 or later and JavaScript enabled for this to work.
</div>
```

[The reference is here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html).

Comment: Thanx jeffamaphone, it's as much complete answer as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to provide the value to Flash?  If so, you need to wrap your name/value pair in the "flashVars" parameter. Like so:

```
<param name="flashVars" value="play=true" />
```

Comment: and your jQuery syntax looks a little off, but since jQuery's not my bag, hopefully someone else can step in & help you out with that part...

Comment: Thanx for answer greatdecay. I do trying to provide value to youtube flash object. The problem is that for all browsers except MSIE, modifying '<EMBED>' do the job. But in order to support autoplay in MSIE I must set '<PARAM>' tag properties, and I can't figure out how to do it for MSIE. Anyway I tried to add '<PARAM>' as you adviced but still nothing. P.S: jQuery may look a bit off becasue I'm not using a '$' - compatibility issues :)